# Firebase topic sync succeeded but not shown in FCM Console

Tags: firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have successfully implemented Push Notification  in Xamarin.Android native App in VS2015 using Firebase Cloud Messaging from console. I tried to subscribe topic from Android App and would like to send push notification from console to all devices whoever subscribed to the topic. Unfortunately console did not show any topic...
App's logcat message is as

```
12-23 02:37:00.269 D/HomeNavigationActivity( 7745): Subscribed to remote notifications
12-23 02:37:00.331 D/FirebaseInstanceId( 7745): topic sync succeeded
```

When I check back in console it shows this project does not have any topic.

Does anybody have similar problem? Or any suggestion or idea would be highly appreciated....

Thank you
Note: Remember I was able to send single devices message using Firebase Cloud Messaging token.

Comment: It takes a few hours before new topics show up in the Firebase Console. You can already send messages to the topics through the API, but you'll have to wait for it to show up in the Firebase Notification console.

Comment: Thank you for your reply though. Finally I got the topic visible on console after waiting hours and hours as you mentioned. However, I tried to send topic message from server which is MVC Web App in my case I was unable to send the notification. My Log cat error message of server is as

Comment: Sorry @Frank, I was unable to complete my error msg as I could not edit because of low reputations. This is my log cat msg of server side {"multicast_id":8284382314884631740,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}. If you have any idea just pop up here.

Comment: @IshworKhanal Can you provide the sample payload you're sending?

Comment: @AL thank you for asking sample payload bwy I was able to fix the problem on my own. Payload was ` var data = new
                {
                   // to = Config.FCM_DEVICE_ID,
                   to="/topics/"+_topic,
                    notification=new
                    {
                        title=_title,
                        body=_message,
                        //icon="myicon"
                    }
                };`

Answer (score 0):

It takes a few hours before new topics show up in the Firebase Console. You can already send messages to the topics through the API, but you'll have to wait for it to show up in the Firebase Notification console.

Source: [Firebase topic sync succeeded but not shown in FCM Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286920/firebase-topic-sync-succeeded-but-not-shown-in-fcm-console#comment69777461_41286920)